# Anyone can help me for creating a Custom Payment methods in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: payment-methods, paypal

I have APIs shared by the Paypal team, I want to configure them to one of Magento's custom payment modules.
Front-end Workflow;

1-Customer adds two products sold by two different suppliers

2-Customer pays for items and is charged once

3-Custom extension sends Supplier information to Paypal Partner account

4-Paypal automatically sends the total amount to each supplier of the order

5-Partner account receive a % of the order placed

Comment: Best way is to probably copy already existing code and modify it to fit your needs. With Payment gateway plugins you should not probably experiment and build from scratch. Start with a simple payment gateway and improve on it.

Comment: Thanks, @KalvinKlien for the suggestion. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payment in Paypal is deprecated

You can ask PayPal about the payout for multiple recipients in Current API, if they provide details use them by overriding the Magento PayPal payment module.

OR try to ask these extension's vendors

https://www.vnecoms.com/magento2-paypal-adaptive-payment-method.html

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-2/magento2-marketplace-paypal-adaptive.html

Reference:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/large-batch-payouts/

[deprecated]

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/